# manually add UITabBar to UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uitabbar

I have a standard app with a navigation controller managing several UITableViewController classes.

I want to add a UITabBar to the root view (a UITableViewController) to manage filtering the selection of objects showin in the UITableView.

I dont want/need a UITabBarController.  The UITabBar is only for functionality and UI (radio-button style selection and familiar tabbar UI).  I just want to manually create a UITabBar and add it to my view anchored/locked to the very bottom of the screen like is the case when using UITabBarControllers.

My main problem is I can't figure out what I should be adding the UITabBar as a subview too.

I dont want to add it to the controllers self.tableView because then it would be achored to the bottom of the scrolling TableView and not always visible on the bottom of the screen.

I also tried adding to the view.tableView.superview but that didnt seem to work as well.

Any help, or am I completely doing this "filtering of tableview data the wrong way" and should be using something else instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, the problem with a `UITableViewController` is it doesn't quite work as you might expect. It's very difficult to add 'locked' elements to a UITableView - the table footers and headers don't do the job, and as you've discovered adding it to the superview doesn't work.

The best solution in this case is actually to throw the table view controller out the window, and use a table view with a normal view controller.

What you want to do is create a normal `UIViewController`, and then add a table view to it. Your table view delegate and datasource can also be in this view controller.

You can then resize your table view to be smaller than the size of the screen, and add your `UITabBar` to the view controller's main view.

Comment: ok, that makes sense.  Let me ask is there an alternative to using a UITabBar to do what I want.  Is it even worth the trouble trying to make a UIToolbar mimic a UITabBar (visually) which I could then just use as the UITableView's toolbar?  

I'm not against creating a plain UIViewController programatically, just curious

Comment: I guess you could. You would need a bit of trickery/hackery to get your toolbar looking exactly like a tab bar - a tab bar is about 6 pixels taller than a tool bar, and you'd also need to re implement all the logic you get for free on a tab bar. But it would certainly be one approach.