# UiTableCell is keeping selected

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I created a ViewController with a tableview in it because i needed an tabbar but when i select a cell to go to an detailview and i'm gonna back the cell is still selected. (same with the tabbar)

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? All my code is the same as a Tableviewcontroller

https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8HLC.png

Or; is it possible to add a Tabbar to a Tableviewcontroller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: hmm... where did you write it? Also you can add this line in the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to deselect the row. In the method *viewWillAppear* of your view controller add the code to deselect the selected tableview row. (hints: [indexPathForSelectedRow](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/indexPathForSelectedRow) and [deselectRowAtIndexPath: animated:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated:))

Moreover, on your second question I think you can find a good answer in another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930526/manually-add-uitabbar-to-uitableviewcontroller).

Hope this helps =)